# SQL : number different dates within users

Tags: mysql, sql

I know this question must have been asked before but I can't find it when I am looking around. Basically I have a table with column 1 and 2, and I want to know how I can construct column 3 of this table:

```
user   date         number
---------------------------
 1     2017-08-22     1
 1     2017-08-22     1
 1     2017-09-12     2
 1     2017-09-12     2
 1     2017-10-15     3
 2     2017-05-23     1
 2     2017-07-24     2
```

Anyone got an idea?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The answer will perhaps be product specific.)

Comment: Looks like you need to use rank on date column

Comment: in MySQL @jarlh

Comment: will try that @LJ

Comment: Does MySQL have RANK?

Comment: does not seem like it does @jarlh, but I found this now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333665/rank-function-in-mysql which is hopefully enough to solve the problem

Comment: Subquery might work: _SELECT et.user, et.date, (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT date) FROM exampleTable WHERE user = et.user AND date <= et.date) AS number
FROM exampleTable AS et 
ORDER BY user ASC;_ @TrotteBoman

Comment: That seems to produce something like what I wanted. I will experiment with it a little further but I think you might have got it @Magisch

Comment: @TrotteBoman I posted it as an answer for future reference

Comment: Marked as solved, thanks! @Magisch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other then Rownumber shenanigans a subquery might do the trick:

```
SELECT
et.user,
et.date,
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT date) FROM exampleTable WHERE user = et.user AND date <= et.date) AS number
FROM exampleTable AS et 
ORDER BY user ASC;
```

This works by making `number` the amount of occurences of distinct dates lower then or equal to the current date.

Detailed breakdown:

- You're trying to "rank" the dates for any given user.
- Therefore multiple occurences of one date aren't counted (COUNT(DISTINCT))
- The rank of each row is the amount of unique dates lower then or equal to it that came before

You can try it out online [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f914f1/1/0)